# Algebra involving trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let
$$a=cos{π\over9}$$
Prove that if 
$$x+ya+za^2=0$$
and $x,y,z$ are rational numbers, then $x=y=z=0$.

I have tried multiplying with $a$ and writing $a^3={1 \over 8}+{3a \over 4}$.

Comment: I have tried multiplying with "a"and write $$a^3={1 \over 8}+{3a \over 4}$$.Shortly, i tried to reduce it to a form of  $$A+Br=0$$where r is irrational

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $f(x)=8x^3-6x-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$(which can be proved via rational root theorem), with $f(a)=0$(as you've already observed). Suppose $f_0(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is one of the polynomials of the least degree satisfying $f_0(a)=0$. Show by division algorithm that $f_0(x)\mid f(x)$, and conclude from the irreducibility of $f(x)$ that $\deg f_0=3$.